# Summing over a range of values of a values of a variable in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I was wondering how to sum over some specific values of a variable instead of all values in CPLEX. For example,

```
    range shovels = 1..p;
    range faces = 1..f;
    range periods = 1..t;

    dvar boolean a[shovels][faces][periods];
    dvar float+  x[shovels][faces][periods];
    dvar int l[faces][periods];
    dvar int pd[periods];
    dvar int nd[periods];

    //Objective function

    minimize sum (p in shovels, f in routes, t in periods) (x[1][f][t]* RM[p]* TT* Dc[f]* Ht + 
    x[2][f][t]* RM[p]* TT* Dw* Ht + x[1][f][t]* RM[p]* TT* C* Lc;'
```

The symbols not defined are parameters. Defining everything is making it too big. I want to know how to define this objective in CPLEX where the the variable x[shovel][faces][periods] can be summed for all faces and periods but for a specific or range of values of shovel?
I have similar problem in constraint too where I need to sum over some values of the index, not forall values.

Comment: Can you not just create a new set which is a subset of the shovel index values (e.g. {int} subset = {1,3,7};), and then define your sum using that subset like sum (p in subset, f in routes, ...)

Answer (score 0):

you could have a look at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooarrayvariableindexertupleset.mod within [Making Optimization Simple](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/)

```
int nbKids=300;

tuple busscenario
{
  key int nbSeats;
  key int scenario;
  float cost;
}

{busscenario} busscenarii={<40,1,500>,<30,1,400>,<30,2,410>,<35,2,440>,<40,2,520>}; 

{int} scenarii={i.scenario | i in busscenarii};

// decision variable array with variable size
dvar int+ nbBus[busscenarii];

// objective
minimize
     1/card(scenarii)*sum(sc in scenarii,b in busscenarii:b.scenario==sc) b.cost*nbBus[b];
     
// constraints
subject to
{
   forall(sc in scenarii) sum(b in busscenarii:b.scenario==sc) b.nbSeats*nbBus[b]>=nbKids;
}

execute
{
  for(sc in scenarii)
  {
    writeln("scenario ",sc);
    for(var b in busscenarii) if (b.scenario==sc) writeln(nbBus[b]," buses ",b.nbSeats," seats" );
    writeln();
  }
}
```